# signalr method not being triggered in onSleep event xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-signalr, application-lifecycle

i am trying to implement a way to detect the user's status if online or offline. so i used the lifecycle events in xamarin.forms. i set online flag to false when the app goes to the background, then send it using a signalr hub method:

```
 async  protected override void OnSleep()
        {
                online = false;
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("userid", "")) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("permission", "")))
                {
                    if (Preferences.Get("permission", "") == "Student")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                             await SendMessage(Preferences.Get("userid", ""), false);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {
                            MessagingCenter.Send(this, App.UpdateStatusErrorMessage, exp.Message);
                        }

                    
                        await updateuserstatus(Preferences.Get("userid", ""));

                    }
                    
                }
       
        }
```

but it is not being triggered unless it is the second time or third time the app goes to the background. i tried adding `Task.Delay(500)` then calling `base.OnSleep()` but nothing is working. any suggestions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to update your presence when the user navigates away from the page, the [Page.OnDisappearing Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.ondisappearing?view=xamarin-forms) may be more suitable.

```
protected override async void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    
    online = false;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("userid", "")) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("permission", "")))
    {
        if (Preferences.Get("permission", "") == "Student")
        {
            try
            {
                await SendMessage(Preferences.Get("userid", ""), false);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send(this, App.UpdateStatusErrorMessage, exp.Message);
            }
            
            await updateuserstatus(Preferences.Get("userid", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

And if you still want use `OnSleep` event, you can try the code below.

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    online = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("userid", "")) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get("permission", "")))
    {
        if (Preferences.Get("permission", "") == "Student")
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await SendMessage(Preferences.Get("userid", ""), false);
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        MessagingCenter.Send(this, App.UpdateStatusErrorMessage, exp.Message);
                    });
                }

                await updateuserstatus(Preferences.Get("userid", ""));
            });
        }
    }

    base.OnSleep();
}
```